# Using text-shadow in HTML email with inline CSS

Tags: html, css, html-email

Is it possible to use the text-shadow feature with inline CSS? I am trying to give my header a border, but nothing seems to work. I am writing this for an email template in an IT ticketing application, so I can't add a separate style sheet. It seems my options are limited. Maybe my syntax is wrong?

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">
<span style="font-family: Verdana">
<span style="text-shadow: -1px -1px #ffffff, -1px 1px #ffffff, 1px -1px #ffffff, 1px 1px #ffffff">
    Service Request Created
</span>
</span>
</h1>
```

Please let me know if what I am trying to do is even possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an inline issue. Email clients limit many CSS properties. Text shadow does not work on all popular clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/.

One solution is that you can make the text an image.

Also, inline style declarations should still end with semicolons.

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure this is correct. May try the image route. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way could be using double texts (adjust the shadow color to fit your requirements).

*Do note, as commentend by [ShaunOReilly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228161/using-text-shadow-in-html-email-with-inline-css#comment74341136_36228405),`position: absolute` (and likely `opacity` too) aren't supported in all email clients*

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center">
  <span style="font-family: Verdana; position: relative">
    <span style="position: absolute; left: 2px; top: 2px; width: 100%; color: #f00; opacity: 0.5; ">
      Service Request Created
    </span>
    <span style="position: relative">
      Service Request Created
    </span>
  </span>
</h1>
```

---

Updated

Not so long time ago I ran into another way of *positioning* elements without using `absolute`. Its been tested and worked more or less everywhere <sup>(but Outlook Desktop)</sup>, but since the below linked article is 2 years old, it might even work in today's version of Outlook Desktop.

```html
<div style="width:300px;height:300px;outline:2px solid black;margin:0 auto;">  
    <div style="max-height:0;max-width:0;">
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-top:100px;margin-left:100px;display:inline-block;outline:2px solid red;text-align:center;line-height:100px;font-size:50px;background:rgba(255,0,0,0.2)">
            1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="max-height:0;max-width:0;">
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-top:150px;margin-left:150px;display:inline-block;outline:2px solid blue;text-align:center;line-height:100px;font-size:50px;background:rgba(0,0,255,0.2)">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="max-height:0;max-width:0;">
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px;margin-top:50px;margin-left:50px;display:inline-block;outline:2px solid green;text-align:center;line-height:100px;font-size:50px;background:rgba(0,255,0,0.2)">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Src: http://blog.rebelmail.com/absolute-positioning-in-email/

Comment: absolute positioning does not work in allot of email clients!

Comment: @ShaunOReilly Thanks for your comment. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me, I just changed the color of the shadow.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzurn53p/)

```
<span style="text-shadow: -1px -1px #f00, -1px 1px #f00, 1px -1px #f00, 1px 1px #f00">
```

You can also check this article to see compatibility of CSS3 on email clients :

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/04/css3-support-in-email-clients/

Answer (score 0):

Your css looks correct and works for me. Is the text shown on a dark background? Because it might be difficult to see white text shadow on bright backgrounds. Also try adding !important at the end of the style. Also check with your browsers element inspector, wether your style is overridden.

Comment: !important didn't work. I think it just doesn't work on this client.

Comment: `!important` is usually not a good solution anyways. [Obligatory CommitStrip](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/02/26/nothing-is-more-important-than-the-cascade/) :-)